# Ordering of user-define functions inside another user-define function PHP

Tags: php

I dont understand how ordering works when using function inside a function.

```
function funcChild(){
    echo "Sparta";
}

function funcMain($panic){
    echo "This is $panic";
}



funcMain(funcChild());
```

It outputs:

```
SpartaThis is
```

I just want it to output "This is Sparta".

Comment: modify funcChild to return rather than echo; or call funcChild with output buffering, and then pass that buffer value to funcMain

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to `return` the value from the function so it can be passed to the next function, not `echo` it right there on the spot.

Comment: May I borrow your eyes?

Comment: Afraid I need them myself. :P

Comment: Legit and understandable... :D

Answer (score 1):

`echo` and `return` are not equivalent. When you echo something, it gets immediately printed, rather than stored anywhere. When your code executes, `funcChild()` executes first because `funcMain()` is trying to use it as a parameter. `funcChild()` echos "Sparta" to the screen, and then returns nothing for `funcMain()` to use. That means `funcMain()` runs with no input.

Change `echo "Sparta"` to `return "Sparta"`

```
function funcChild(){
    return "Sparta";
}

function funcMain($panic){
    echo "This is $panic";
}

funcMain(funcChild());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function funcChild(){
    return "Sparta";
}

function funcMain($panic){
    echo "This is $panic";
}



funcMain(funcChild());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is like mathematics, it starts from the inside out, you must generate a return and not a direct print

```
function funcChild(){
    return "Sparta"; // return ... not direct print!
}

function funcMain($panic){
    echo "This is $panic";
}



funcMain(funcChild());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your code to this:

```
function funcMain($panic) {
  echo "This is $panic";
}
```

and be done? I cannot see any reason why you would want or need to do what you are trying. However, the reason you are getting the results you are getting is because the call to funcChild is happening as an argument of funcMain. Therefore, funcChild executes first, then funcMain executes.

If you absolutely have to do what you are trying, then
    funcChild(funcMain()) should be how to do it.